# Convergence of a series: question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I know
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{\,%
{2\cos\left({\left[k - 1\right]\pi \over n-3}\right) -
2\cos\left(k\pi \over n + 1\right)}\,\right\} = 0,
$$
for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
$$
\mbox{Can I conclude}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
\left\vert\,{2\cos\left({\left[k - 1\right]\pi \over n-3}\right) -
2\cos\left(k\pi \over n + 1\right)}\,\right\vert = 0\ {\large ?}
$$
I think I can't. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
we can't conclude that
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k} = 0} $$

In your case
$$2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{n-3}\right)-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n+1}\right)=\\-4 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}-\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}+\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right)$$
and
$$\left|\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n -4 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}-\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}+\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right)\right)\right|=4$$

Comment: you are right. I know this example. But I want to prove or disprove.

Comment: @Nmath i have edited my answer. There is no proof because I used a software to get the result. Hope it is enogh for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to compute $\sum |.|$. You forgot the abs. Can i ask you which software did you use?

Comment: @Nmath Wolfram mathematica 12.0. The sum of the abs values if greater or equal to the abs of the sum

Comment: What does it mean $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -4 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}-\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (k-1)}{2 (n-3)}+\frac{\pi  k}{2 (n+1)}\right)=2$$ if we are assuming $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @user I edited my answer and realized I made a silly mistake. The limit is 4. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{\,%
{2\cos\left({\left(k - 1\right)\pi \over n-3}\right) -
2\cos\left(k\pi \over n + 1\right)}\,\right\} = 0$$ is true because for large values of $n$
$$2\cos\left({\left(k - 1\right)\pi \over n-3}\right) -
2\cos\left(k\pi \over n + 1\right)=\frac{(2k-1)\pi^2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ But, as an example
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k-1)\pi^2}{n^2}=\pi^2$$ In fact, you have two summations of cosines where the arguments are in arithmetic progression, and, after simplifications, omitting the absolute value,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{\,%
{2\cos\left({\left(k - 1\right)\pi \over n-3}\right) -
2\cos\left(k\pi \over n + 1\right)}\,\right\}=1+\cos \left(\frac{5 \pi  (n-2)}{2 (n-3)}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{2 (n-3)}\right) \to -4$$

Quoting @Raffaele's comment *"the sum of the abs values if greater or equal to the abs of the sum"*, using the absolute value of the sum. For the infinite sum, the  result would be $ > 4$.

For example, using $n=15$, without absolute values, we should get $\left(-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)\approx -3.66390$ while with absolute values the result would be
$$4+\sqrt{3}+3 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}-4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-4 \cos
   \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\approx 4.50621$$

Comment: Please expand the step where you use the big $O$ notation, I am unable to understand how to get there